# use a function to not rewrite all ids

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I am still the begininer in javascript.. I guess it can be written simpler, without retyping those IDs. Html file has got matching ids to clear after the form is resulted.

```
function deleteValues() {
    document.getElementById('firstFemale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('secondFemale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('thirdFemale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('mistakeFemale').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('resultFemale').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('firstMale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('secondMale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('thirdMale').value = "";
    document.getElementById('mistakeMale').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('resultMale').innerHTML = "";
}
```

but what if I had a lot of different IDs? I know getElementbyId can only retract one element.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the inputs `document.getElementById("yourFormId").reset();` or `<input type="reset">` For innerHTML, common class and a forEach

Comment: [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @epascarello - Darned fine idea, if they're in a `form` and their default values are `""`. But it's not going to help with the `innerHTML` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take multiple approaches, but I'd probably add a class to the elements so you get could get a list of them. For instance, you might give them the class `to-clear` (`class="to-clear"`) and then:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".to-clear").forEach(element => {
    if ("value" in element) {
        element.value = "";
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

More: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)